# Bypassing Access-Control-Allow-Headers header

Tags: json, xml, xxe

What i want to do is access the Content-type header which is placed under the Access-Control-Allow-Headers header as i want to attempt to change json to xml on a web application im working on to check if its vulnerable to XML or XXE injection.

Answer (score 1):

XML entity attacks are attacks against the server, not the client. CORS headers like Access-Control-Allow-* are only relevant to the client. You completely ignore them when testing for purely-server-side vulnerabilities. Just use Burp Suite / ZAP / Fiddler (or `curl`, or your browser's dev tools, or `nc`) to change the content-type header and the payload.

With that said, the likelihood that a server which expects only JSON will see a request containing XML instead and decide "better load that into an XML-parsing library" rather than "WTF is this nonsense **400 BAD REQUEST**" is... very low.